# How do I resolve this Weblogic intermittent java.lang.LinkageError? What are the steps to understanding what it means and fix it?

Tags: java, exception, weblogic, classloader, linkage

I have an intermittent linkage error thrown: (That's basically all the information I have)

```
java.lang.LinkageError loader constraint violation: 
  when resolving field 'service' of the class loader instance of 
  java/net/FactoryURLClassLoader) of the referring class 
  org/apache/axis/client/Stub, and the class loader (instance of
  weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) 
  for the field's resolved type, java/xml/rpc/Service, 
  have different class objects for that type
```

Or in a  more readable way

- **Exception:** java.lang.LinkageError

  - **field:** `service`
  - **CL instance:** `java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader`
  - **reffering class:** `org.apache.axis.client.Stub`
  - **2nd CL instance:** `weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader`
  - **field's resolve type:** `java.xml.rpc.Service`

Does this mean that I have 2 versions of java.xml.rpc.Service loaded? Is that so? How can that happen? what is the way to resolve it?

Comment: Is this deployed in an EAR with an APP-INF/lib folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was eventually to update the `weblogic-application.xml` file of the deployed app

The application used an old `jaxrpc-api.jar` that we could not remove for various  reason,

The solution we used to prefer the internal jar was this (Is there a better way?)

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
  ...
  <wls:package-name>java.xml.rpc.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Comment: This appears to work only for EAR files and not for WAR files

Comment: True, it works only for EAR files. To make it work on WAR files update weblogic.xml instead of weblogic-application.xml with the same snippet.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that I have 2 versions of java.xml.rpc.Service loaded? Is that so?

Yes.

> How can that happen?

It happens when you have two classloaders both loading the same class.  In your case, the classloaders are instances of different ClassLoader classes:

```
    java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader
```

and

```
    weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader
```

> what is the way to resolve it?

I'm not a Weblogic user, but the theoretical solution is to put the JAR file containing the classes in question into the classpath of an common ancestor classloader of the two above.