# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask

Tags: java, ant, weblogic

When we are running build from jenkins on our build server, getting below exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(Ljava/io/Writer;Ljavax/tools/JavaFileManager;Ljavax/tools/DiagnosticListener;Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/sun/source/util/JavacTask;" the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) of the current class, com/bea/util/jam/internal/javadoc/JavadocClassBuilder, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, com/sun/tools/javac/api/JavacTool, have different Class objects for the type com/sun/source/util/JavacTask used in the signature
     [exec]     at com.bea.util.jam.internal.javadoc.JavadocClassBuilder.getImports(JavadocClassBuilder.java:212)
     [exec]     at com.bea.util.jam.internal.javadoc.JavadocClassBuilder.build(JavadocClassBuilder.java:140)
     [exec]     at com.bea.util.jam.provider.CompositeJamClassBuilder.build(CompositeJamClassBuilder.java:51)
     [exec]     at com.bea.util.jam.internal.JamClassLoaderImpl.loadClass(JamClassLoaderImpl.java:128)
     [exec]     at com.bea.util.jam.internal.JamServiceImpl.getAllClasses(JamServiceImpl.java:65)
     [exec]     at weblogic.wsee.util.JamUtil.parseSource(JamUtil.java:168)
     [exec]     at weblogic.wsee.util.JamUtil.parseSource(JamUtil.java:136)
     [exec]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsLoader.loadJClasses(JwsLoader.java:187)
     [exec]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsLoader.load(JwsLoader.java:75)
     [exec]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.loadWebServices(JwsModule.java:631)
     [exec]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.generate(JwsModule.java:432)
     [exec]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.build(JwsModule.java:306)
     [exec]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:242)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [exec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
     [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)
```

we are using Weblogic 12 and Java 8. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to load a class with two classloaders, (java/net/URLClassLoader, and sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader). But both loaders disagree on the class that is defined.

You need to make sure the class is on the classpath of only one classloader.

Since we don't know why the class is in the classpath of multiple classloaders, I can't really give an answer on how to resolve the issue, but the following sources may be able to help:

[How do I resolve this Weblogic intermittent java.lang.LinkageError? What are the steps to understanding what it means and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997212/how-do-i-resolve-this-weblogic-intermittent-java-lang-linkageerror-what-are-the)

and

[The java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation" demystified](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2009/03/javalanglinkageerror-loader-constraint.html)

Comment: <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1.2</wls:weblogic-version>
        <wls:context-root>SoegStatusService</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
         <wls:prefer-application-packages>
             <wls:package-name>com.sun.source.util.*</wls:package-name>
         </wls:prefer-application-packages>
     </wls:container-descriptor>
    </wls:weblogic-web-app>

Comment: I tried adding   <wls:package-name>com.sun.source.util.*</wls:package-name> but it didn't work. Moreover, when I am running it manually on build server , it is working fine. issue is coming when build is triggered from jenkins.